# G++ не видит файлы для привязки SDL2 библеотеки

Tags: g++, sdl2

При попытке скомпилировать `c++` код с использованием библиотеки `SDL2` с помощью `g++`, выдаёт ошибку:

```
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main: No such file or directory
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2: 
No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Команда для компиляции:

```
g++ -Isrc/Include -Lsrc -o main main.cpp -l mingw64 -l SDL2main -l SDL2
```

Делал по [туториалу](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H08t6gD1Y1E), там используется 32-битная `SDL2`, я сделал всё тоже самое, только для 64-битной. SDL скачал с [гитхаба](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.26.5), версия `SDL2-devel-2.26.5-mingw.tar.gz`. Для 32-битной такая же ошибка. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```